# Using “Had Born” in English sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, sentence-structure

Can I Use “Had Born” in English sentence to express past perfect i.e. past of past?

1)  He had born when I reached to the Hospital.

2)  This is where I had born.

3)  Your father came to hospital but before that you had born.

4)  He had born in India.

Why Born is adjective and died is Verb?
Also What verb for bron then?

Comment: *Born* in this sense is always used with *BE*, so the perfect will be *HAVE **been** born*: the present/past perfects are *I have/had been born, he has/had been born, you/we/they have/had been born*

Comment: @Stoney is right, but, for two of these sentences, I think most native speakers would just use "was": _This is where I was born. He was born in India._

Comment: Perhaps because dying is something you do, whereas being born is something that happens to the infant that is going to become you.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the passive with **born** (*to be born*).

Your sentences would be correct like so:

> 1) He **had** already **been** born when I reached the Hospital.
>
> 2) This is where I **was** born.
>
> 3) Your father came to hospital but that was before you **were** born.
>
> 4) He **was** born in India.

The past participle *born* is one of the two different past participles from the word *to bear* (*borne* & *born*). However, when referring to birth, *born* is used and can only be used in the passive form. Therefore you can only find it in combination with the verb **have** as an auxiliary verb in perfect tenses:

> - He **has** been born.
> - He **had** been born.

You cannot omit the verb *to be* in your sentence, it is required to form the passive. **Born** cannot be used in and active phrase, not when you're talking about birth.

To form active sentences when talking about birth, you use *borne*. However, with that past participle, it is the subject who is performing the act of giving birth while the object is the one that starts his life.

> She *has borne* two children.

This website contains some solid information on the difference between *born* and *borne*: [Borne vs. born - Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/spelling/borne-born/)

Comment: 'borne' is a verb I hear often at all.  From the verb to bear yes?  From to carry.  I never made to connection from born/bare/carry until now.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's the past participle of *to bear*. And so is *born*, though each of them has a different meaning as I explained above.

Comment: Yes, the meanings are clear to me as I'm a native speaker, but even so, I'm still amazed at all the little dirty corners of the langauge I still run across.  Good answer.

Comment: Ahh, I thought you were asking me something, my bad :P And yes, I kmow what you mean, I've had similar experiences in my native language as well

Comment: Number 1 should be, "He was born when I reached the hospital." No "to". Number 3 should be, "Your father came to the hospital before you were born", or "Your father came to the hospital, but that was before you were born." "You" takes the plural verb "were" even when used in the singular.

Comment: Oops, seems I overlooked OP's errors. Fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @Jay Since OP specifically asks about past perfect, I take it that what is intended here is *He had (already) been born when I reached the hospital*.

Comment: @StoneyB Ok, I'll go with that.

Comment: *Born* is very unusual as a passive verb form. Usually, we can indicate the agent with a *by*-phrase in passive clauses, but that doesn't work with *born*.

Answer (score 1):

Nos. 1 and 3 are interesting sentences, here is how I would say those:

> When I reached the hospital, he had already been born.
>
> Your father arrived at the hospital too late; you had already been born.

Comment: Funny how I would use 'already arrived' instead of 'been born' on your second example.  Let's us get rid of that troublesome 'been'  :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - Hmmm... _Your father arrived at the hospital too late; you had already arrived_. That's an interesting twist on the two definitions of the word _arrived_. How about this one? _Your father showed up at the hospital too late; you had already arrived._

Comment: arrived twice doesn't sound poetic enough.  I'd leave came on the first, but arrived on the second :)  Your second one is fun though!

Comment: _By the time your father bore your mother to the hospital,  you had already been born. He could not bear the sight of you_

Comment: how very boring :)

Answer (score 0):

Any are valid if changed to

> had *been* born.

As far as tense:

> born:dead :: to bear:to die

Technically, born is a past participle, not an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

*Born* is an adjective.  So you must use a form of *to be* with it as you would any other adjective, if you are saying X is that quality/state described by the adjective.

*To bear* is a verb which means to give birth, and the past participle form of *to bear* is *borne*.  However, the object of *to bear* will be whatever you are giving birth to.

> She had borne a child.

If you want to identify your place of birth, say:

> I was born in Memphis.